# Downloaded file is corrupted shared by client in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

I tried to create the file on server side using the inputstream which I am getting from client side.

File is created with the same size as of original file. But when trying to open it is showing that file is corrupted.

**fileSharing.jsp on client server** which is trying to share file **(Sender)**

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
OutputStream os = null;
InputStream is = null;
try {
    File fileObj = new File("D://test.pdf");
    out.print("File Length " + fileObj.length() + " Name " + fileObj.getName());
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:2080/Receiver/fileupload?filename=test.pdf&filelength=" + fileObj.length());
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"Dummy File Description\"");
    httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(8192);
    httpURLConnection.connect();

    is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileObj));
    os = new BufferedOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

    byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
        os.write(buff, 0, len);
        os.flush();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    is.close();
    os.close();
    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
}
```

**FileUploadController servlet on server side** which is trying to download the file **(Receiver)**

```
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    is = request.getInputStream();
    int total = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D://files//dummy.pdf")));
    byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
    while (true) {
        if ((bytes = is.read(new byte[8192])) == -1) {
            System.out.println("File shared successfully");
            System.out.println("Total " + total);
            break;
        }
        total = total + bytes;
        System.out.println("Length " + bytes);
        os.write(buff, 0, bytes);
        //os.flush();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: You are reading into one buffer and writng from another. Don't flush inside loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the reading loop of `FileUploadController` you instantiate a new array and read into it, but you don't hold on to it to continue using it:

```
 byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
 while(true){
     if((bytes = is.read(new byte[8192])) == -1){
```

Yet, you *write* `buff` to the file (which will be full of 0-bytes, so you'll have a file with the correct length, but it's full of 0 instead of the actual data).

Replace that last line with

```
     if((bytes = is.read(buff)) == -1){
```

Comment: The code is working fine. But it is breaking if I enable the authentication filter. Can you please help me out ?